# How do I restrict image upload height & width on Rails file_field helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, file-upload, upload, height

Currently I have the below to upload an image:

```
<%= file_field "form_x", "image", accept: 'image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg' %>
```

In my method, I can access the image with this

```
params[:form_x][:image]
```

And access the `size` of the image by reading it through `params[:form_x][:image].size`. But how can I check the image's height and width by pixels? I want to be able to restrict the image by size as well as height and width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way is to do it on client side. You need some javascript, here is an example.

*You unable to get the image width and heigth from params.*

<sub>The only way to do it on the server is to use some preprocessing with [carrierwave for example](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-Get-image-dimensions), **but much more better restrict images on the client side without uploading**.</sub>

html

```
<input id="image" name="img" type="file" />
/*  */
<img src="#" alt="This image is going to load" id="image_on_load" />
<p id='image_info_width'>    </p>
<p id='image_info_heigth'>    </p>
```

the js code:

```
// The upload listner function
$('#image').on('change', function() {
  var img = document.getElementById('image_on_load');
  var reader = new FileReader();
  // add uploaded image to the img element
  reader.onloadend = function() {
    $('#image_on_load').prop('src', reader.result)
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
  // listen onload event and get dimension
  img.onload = function(image) {

    $('#image_info_width').text('Width: ' + image.target.width)
    $('#image_info_heigth').text('Height: ' + image.target.height)
    // here you able to upload or reject
    // file accourding to dimension
  }
});
```

In this example image was uploaded and the you able to get the width and the height.

[`JSFIDDLE`](https://jsfiddle.net/fishbullet/hzevas04/36/)

Read how the works with JS in Rails 
[`7 Must-Reads about JavaScript with Ruby on Rails`](https://www.netguru.co/blog/java-script-ruby-on-rails-resources)

Comment: is this only possible on the client side? there's no way to check on server side?

Comment: the only way to do it on the server is use some preprocessing with carrierwave for example, but much more better restrict images on the client side without uploading.